# Camera calibration - focal length changes from time to time

Tags: opencv, camera

I'm trying to find the intrinsic parameters for my camera using OpenCV. I used the sample - calibration.cpp - and a checkerboard to measure them. However, though I'm using a fixed focus camera, the focal length varies a little between each test.

These are the results from several tests. The fx and fy values are similar, so I'm only posting the fx values:

```
3.9869223033563202e+02
3.7577797715301182e+02
3.4015591014469499e+02
4.0061061135990235e+02
3.7062145833776810e+02
3.6408186454431029e+02
3.4346651456457221e+02
2.2834665446966852e+02
```

Is this normal? My reprojection errors are around 1 to 2, which I feel are a little bit high.

Besides, I fixed the camera at 1 location, but the extrinsic parameters also changes a lot every time.

I'm using an Axis M1011-w camera, the focal length is 4.4mm.

Comment: Question is unclear, can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @BenderBending um... like what?

Comment: Oh I missed the line right underneath the code block, sorry!